# ICS for only Specific IP using Firewall

Tags: windows-7, lan, windows-firewall

Can I share internet connection just for a couple of specific IPs instead of whole Local Area Network (static IP assigned to all machines).

If it's not possible using windows default firewall, is there any free / budget software compatible with this OS?

Answer (score 0):

You CAN do this with the standard W7 firewall.

However, you will need to familiarise yourself with creating custom firewall settings. You need to create two inbound custom rules. Rules are processed in order:

1. First rule is to ALLOW inbound access from a set of IP addresses. The custom firewall rules dialog allows you to add as many as you like
2. The second rule is to BLOCK inbound access from ALL IP addresses.

The first rule takes preference so between them, this should work. I'm afraid I don't have a setup to test this just now. Type "firewall" into the start menu to find the firewall settings application. Then create custom rules as described.

Just make careful notes on what you did so that you can delete the rules if things go wrong and make sure that you test the rules by trying to access your PC from both an allowed and a non-allowed PC.

Comment: I made 2 custom inbound rules. In 1st rule, 2 desired Local IPs allowing Access and the rest setting was default. 2nd rule blocking all Local IPs, (rest setting was default as well). But it did not worked.

Comment: Does it work if you delete the 2nd? Where are the rules in the list - they'll need to be high up so they get processed first (take preference).